# A question about the quotient isomorphism

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

Let $X$, $Y$ be two vector spaces and $f: X \rightarrow Y$ be a surjective map. If $M\subset $ker$f\subset X$ is a subspace, and $X/M$ is isomorphic to $Y$ (it is induce by $f$), can we conclude that $M=$ker$f$?

Comment: In the infinite-dimensional case, no. Only if $f$ induces an isomorphism (but that is trivial).

Comment: @Daniel Fischer Oh, yes the isomorphism is induced by $f$, I have edited my question.

Comment: In that case, calling the induced map $\overline{f}$, we have $\ker \overline{f} = \ker f/M$, and $\overline{f}$ is injective if and only if $M = \ker f$.

Comment: @Daniel Fischer Yeah, you are right, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sami's proof works if the spaces are finite-dimensional.

There is a counter-example in infinite dimensions.

Let $X=\Bbb R\langle v_1,v_2,\dotsc\rangle$ and $Y=\Bbb R\langle v_3,v_4,\dotsc\rangle$. Define $f:X\to Y$ by
$$
f(v_k)=
\begin{cases}
0 & k=1,2\\ 
v_k & k\neq 1,2
\end{cases}
$$
Then $\ker f=\Bbb R\langle v_1,v_2\rangle$. Let $M=\Bbb R\langle v_1\rangle$. Then
$$
X/\ker f=Y\simeq \Bbb R^{\Bbb N}
$$
and
$$
X/M=\Bbb R\langle v_2,v_3,\dotsc\rangle\simeq \Bbb R^{\Bbb N}.
$$

Answer (score 1):

Yes. In fact we have by the rank nullity theorem and since $f$ is surjective:
$$\dim X=\dim Y+\dim\ker f$$
moreover since $X/M$ is isomorphic to $Y$ then
$$\dim X-\dim M=\dim Y$$
hence we have
$$\dim M=\dim\ker f$$
and the result follows since $M\subset \ker f$.

Comment: Not sure if these vector spaces are finite dimensional, judging from the (functional-analysis) tag.

Comment: Ah this proof is valid in finite dimensional space.